# Disabling all UITableViewCells user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey I have a `UITableView`. There are 4 large cells (so they are not all displayed on the screen). At various points through the app I want to disable user interaction for all of them however I am getting a nil unwrap error when I run this code:

```
for row in 0...3 {
     let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 2)) as! AnswerTextChoiceCell
     cell.userInteractionEnabled = reEnable ? true : false
}
```

I'm guessing it's because it can't fetch the cell because it's not displayed on the screen. How Would I go about disabling all user interaction for all the cells?

> I don't want to disable the user interaction on the `tableView` as it will prevent the user from scrolling.

Any pointers on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have an array which has a Boolean value for each cell and update the Boolean values depending on ur requirement. In cellforrowatindexpath check the Boolean array  for cell interaction

Comment: try to disable in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: what is `reEnable`?

Comment: Hoping I get your Question correct

Comment: It looks like reEnable is of Boolean type than what is the meaning of `ternary operator`.

Comment: Exactly!!! there should be some condition instead of `reEnable` or it should not be `ternary`.

Answer (score 4):

Try once.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Configure the cell

        if indexPath.row == yourcell {
           cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        return cell!
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has been updated with **Swift 5** "cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code and your TableView the only two things I can see that would cause that crash would be:

1. When you are casting the cell from 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' to your 'AnswerTextChoiceCell' type
2. You have the wrong section passed in to your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' function

To try and see which of the two it is I would first try omitting the 'AnswerTextChoiceCell' cast completely and see if the problem goes away, or at least that it stops crashing. The function will return a UITableViewCell anyway and the userInteractionEnabled property is available on that object anyway so this will still allow you to test out what you're after.

If that doesn't work then we'll need a bit more information about your table view such as, how many sections do you have, is it storyboard based, etc.